# Bathroom Fan Exhaust Vent Replacement

Tags: bathroom, vent, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

I am having a bit of a tough time finding an Exhaust Vent that will replace the one that we currently have which has some broken louvered pieces. The dimensions of the plate are 5.5" x 5.5". The screws are all 5.125" apart. I am trying to find something to replace it that doesn't require me to drill new holes into the concrete here if I can avoid it. I was hoping to find something like [this](https://www.famcomfg.com/product/hooded-wall-vent-with-spring-loaded-damper-gasket-and-screen-painted/?attribute_pa_size=2d-5inch&attribute_pa_color=48-black&attribute_pa_includes-8%C2%BC-tail-pipe=no&utm_source=Google%20Shopping&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Google%20Shopping%20Feed%20XML&gclid=CjwKCAjwxaanBhBQEiwA84TVXINw5PCNA4Wh6C-i-ygg2SqUm8lbSXi210rGQtj3BdkaC5QHMBkzCBoCP6IQAvD_BwE) to use as the replacement, but really struggling to find anything that is this small dimensionally. Everything seems to be 1/2 - 5/8" larger in a square shape.

Hoping someone here has some ideas. Thanks[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing one screw to determine what kind of screw it is and what it is screwing into? Also, does that center panel have fixed louvers or ones that flip open with airflow?

Comment: Is the hole measure of 5.125 inches apart measured center-to-center?

Comment: This particular exhaust vent is all fixed louvers (which isn’t what I would replace it with).

Comment: Yes, that 5.125” is center to center on the holes.

Comment: they are mostly 6x6, just drill holes in right place

Comment: Is there a *problem* with a vent that's a fraction of an inch bigger?